# Page rendering is slow in pdf-annotate.js

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

Am using pdf-annotate.js for pdf. Its reading the content very fast but while rendering in page its very slow. How can i able to fix the problem?

My render page code:

```
function render() 
    {       
            PDFJS.getDocument(RENDER_OPTIONS.documentId).then(function (pdf) 
            {
            RENDER_OPTIONS.pdfDocument = pdf;
                    var viewer = document.getElementById('viewer');
                    localStorage.getItem(RENDER_OPTIONS.documentId + '/VIEWER'); 
                    if(localStorage.getItem(RENDER_OPTIONS.documentId + '/VIEWER')){
                    viewer.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem(RENDER_OPTIONS.documentId + '/VIEWER');
                    console.log("loaded")
                    console.lo

                    }
                    // else {
                    viewer.innerHTML = '';  
                    // }         
                    NUM_PAGES = pdf.pdfInfo.numPages;

                    for (var i = 0; i < NUM_PAGES; i++) 
                    {
                        console.log(i);
                            var page = UI.createPage(i + 1);

                            viewer.appendChild(page);
                            console.log(page)

            UI.renderPage(i+1, RENDER_OPTIONS).then(function (_ref) {
            console.log(_ref)
                var _ref2 = _slicedToArray(_ref, 2),
                    pdfPage = _ref2[0],
                    annotations = _ref2[1];


                            var viewport = pdfPage.getViewport(RENDER_OPTIONS.scale, RENDER_OPTIONS.rotate);
                            PAGE_HEIGHT = viewport.height;

                            localStorage.setItem(RENDER_OPTIONS.documentId + '/HEIGHT', pdfPage.pageInfo.view[3]);
                    });
                    $("#pgloader").css("display", "none");
                }
             localStorage.setItem(RENDER_OPTIONS.documentId + '/VIEWER',viewer);
          renderedPages.push(1);
        });
    }
```

How do i increase the rendering speed in my application. Kindly help me in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

***Please consider this "answer" just as an opinion piece, orientation, not a helpful answer particularly as I want to just add my 2 cents here.***

---

We have similar problems with [pdf-annotate.js](https://github.com/instructure/pdf-annotate.js), but so far this performance issue is unresolved.

What we did was, we basically **split up larger/more complex PDF files page-by-page**. When the user wants to see a particular page, we show a [spinner](https://spin.js.org/) as long as it's needed, processing that particular page, then when it's done, **store that page in the browser's storage**.

Sadly, this method doesn't fix the real problem, hence consider this as a **temporary duck-tape "fix"**.

---

Please, check out [this issue](https://github.com/instructure/pdf-annotate.js/issues/67) on GitHub regarding performance and report your case there too.

Comment: Have you tried to update the pdf.js and pdf.worker.js version 2012 to 2017